# Calling Stored Procedure with Hibernate and Spring

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring, stored-procedures

There are a lot of examples over the net which describe how to call a stored procedure using Hibernate, however, when using Spring, the picture changes a bit.

I have a stored procedure in MySQL which I want to call:
in SQL I need to write the following:

```
CALL inrange(32.342324,32.234234);
It returns a row with the following: `{INT},{INT},{FLOAT}`
```

With Spring, I use the `HibernateTemplate` way of executing hibernate operations, I know that some of you won't like it, but this is the how the project was when I started, and I'm not so eager changing it, maybe in the future...

Currently, I have the following code in Java, which tries to call the procedure:

```
List<Object[]> resultset = hibernateTemplate
                               .findByNamedQuery("inrange",
                                    person.getAddress().getLatitude(),
                                    person.getAddress().getLongitude());
```

When I run it, I get the following Hibernate exception:

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException:
   Named query not known: inrange;
```

I figured that this is happening duo the fact that I didn't declare the stored procedure in hibernate.
My question is:

- how do I declare it ?
- Is there a special way of declaring it in the Spring's application context file ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call native sql queries within hibernate.

Look at this link:
http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-call-store-procedure-in-hibernate/

Btw if you want to call stored procedures you could simply use a Spring JdbcTemplate.

Notice that an hibernate extension can fit to your needs:
http://www.hibernatespatial.org/

Comment: The Hibernatespatial looks very cool, however I'm using mySQL, and it appears there  that most of the features are not supported on that DB, especially the distance function...

Comment: Actually each DB provides its own features/functions and you can probably contribute to that project so that it works with mySQL too. Good luck

Answer (score 3):

You're confusing Hibernate's named queries with MySQL's stored procedures.

If you want to call the MySQL stored proc, there is no benefit to doing so through Hibernate's API. I recommend you use Spring's JdbcTemplate to perform the query.

If you absolutely must use Hibernate, something like this should work:

```
SQLQuery query = hibernateTemplate.getCurrentSession()
  .createSQLQuery("SELECT inrange(:latitude, :longitude)";
query.setDouble("latitude", ...);
query.setDouble("longitude", ...);
List<Object[]> result = query.list(); // requires casting for generics
```

Comment: I'm not confused, google a bit and you'll find what I'm pointing at.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the named query to your hibernate mapping file.

Can you share your hibernate mapping file? You can find some samples [here](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-named-query-examples/).

Along with the previous link you can go through [this](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#sp_query) also.

It will be easier if you can share the POJO, hibernate mapping and the procedure you are using.

[This blog](http://timezra.blogspot.com/2008/10/spring-hibernate-and-oracle-stored.html) will be of help for you. I hope you will not have any problem with using the `getHibernateTemplate().execute(HibernateCallback)` method.

Comment: Actually, I don't have an Hibernate mapping file. I'm using Spring's context XML & Annotations for hibernate mapping. I can post spring configuration if you find it helpful.

Comment: Can you share the POJO class?

Comment: There's no pojo, the resultset of the stored-procedure, is not mapped to a pojo, it's all scalars.

Comment: The problem with this is that there's no inRange class... It sohuldn't be mapped, it's scallars.

Comment: Then probably you should look at using ResultTransformer as given in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863883/hibernate-mapping-custom-column-names-in-stored-procedure-named-query along with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/602397/how-do-i-externalize-named-queries-in-a-hibernate-annotations-app to externalize the annotation

Answer (score 1):

You can use JPA as Spring supports it either in Core or Spring Data.

Calling the stored procedure can be done using the [`StoredProcedureQuery`](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-call-mysql-stored-procedures-and-functions-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) as follows:

```
StoredProcedureQuery query = entityManager
    .createStoredProcedureQuery("count_comments")
    .registerStoredProcedureParameter(
        "postId", Long.class, ParameterMode.IN)
    .registerStoredProcedureParameter(
        "commentCount", Long.class, ParameterMode.OUT)
    .setParameter("postId", 1L);

query.execute();

Long commentCount = (Long) query
    .getOutputParameterValue("commentCount");
```